# how can i do this simple line animation?

Tags: microsoft-powerpoint, animation

I've been looking on YouTube on how to create this dotted line animation, without success.
I imagine that this is possible to do in power point, but I don't know how. I would appreciate if an expert could help me.

[image]

Comment: Since MS Office' Visio cannot make animated GIF's directly, one could import *frames*, with each line moved a bit, into PowerPoint or another tool. LibreOffice's *Draw* can make animated GIF's, https://help.libreoffice.org/6.1/en-US/text/simpress/guide/animated_gif_create.html

Answer (score 3):

I'm no expert, but believe you can achieve this with [Draw IO](https://app.diagrams.net/) as seen here below.

[image]

Use the web-app to create your diagram, or for now just make a simple flow animation connector arrow as a mere test. After that, I imagine they have an export option that allows you to see it in action in the form of a gif or similar file.

Failing that, you can always use something like [OBS](https://obsproject.com/) to screen capture the diagram with the animated connectors moving, and then import that screen capture file into your video editing software to work with it further.

Please refer to this section of [the guide](https://drawio-app.com/blog/connector-styles-and-animations-in-draw-io/) on how to create animated signal flow connectors in draw io.

[image]

Comment: I tried this out and didn't find any way of exporting the animated flow lines to a format that would animate in PPT, but a screen capture should do the job. You can remove the grid from the View menu. I found that I could use PowerPoint's own screen recording feature to make a quick video of the Draw.io diagram.

Comment: Excellent, it seems a little counter productive that Draw.io provide animated assets but yet do not offer an export option compatible with them. Either way, I'm glad this has resolved the issue for you.

Comment: It wasn't my issue. Perhaps Frank can let us know if it helped him.